# Ireport: labelling time series chart

Tags: charts, jasper-reports

somebody knows how to put a label in a time series chart in iReport?
In the image below, I show how supposed to be the result.
Thanks!

[image: Time Series Chart]

Comment: http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/sample-java-code-time-series-chart-customizer-add-label-chart

Comment: I will try this... Thanks!!! =D